# jQuery / CSS / AJAX Popup-Style DIV closes when result contains div

Tags: jquery, css, html, overlay, wrapper

I made a jQuery / CSS Popup-Style Div. The div's content is loaded through an ajax-request and is put in .ajax_popup_wrapper !

When you hover over TIPP the div is created and appended to "BODY". (.ajax_popup_wrapper_wrapper)

I use these lines in the div function:

```
$('.ajax_popup_wrapper_wrapper').mouseout(function(){
        // REMOVE DIV's
});
```

to check whether the mouse is over the .ajax_popup_wrapper_wrapper or not (if not -> close it!)

This is fine if the ajax_popup_wrapper contains only text and images (or stuff like that!). If the result contains another div (in the picture: RESULT DIV), then you cannot hover this RESULT DIV, because the .ajax_popup_wrapper_wrapper is removed. The RESULT DIV should underlay the wrapper_wrapper, but must **STILL BE CLICKABLE!**

I tried to put the wrapper_wrapper on top of the RESULT DIV and that works (the div is not going to be closed!), but then I can't click on links inside the RESULT DIV..

It's weird, please help me!
Thanks!

**EDIT: I added a JSFIDDLE Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/dH55F/19/

[image]

Comment: did you try to make the `wrapper_wrapper` transparent when it is on top of `result div` ?

Comment: Hi, I tried it with opacity but it doesn't work. The RESULT DIV is not clickable.

Comment: can you add code and a minimal testcase in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I added an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dH55F/19/

Comment: In this example I put the content into the outer wrapper so the div closes when I hover the content div. http://jsfiddle.net/dH55F/20/

Comment: A link withing a link... Ofcourse this won't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this,

```
var mouse_is_inside = false;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.ajax_popup_wrapper_wrapper').hover(function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=false; 
    });


});
```

Ref : [see this](http://stackcomplete.com/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-div-or-element/)

Comment: your answer is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Detect if the element we moved our mouse into has a class [*hopefully you can add an identifier to the div inside of it*], and if it does, return false, otherwise, just do your normal remove code.

```
$('.ajax_popup_wrapper_wrapper').mouseout(function(e){
    if($(e.toElement).hasClass('other')){
        return false;   
    }
    //do your remove code here
});
```

I wasn't sure if the elements were being removed completely from the DOM, so the following code delegates the event handler to any element with a class of `other` that exists in the DOM tree at the time of the click; regardless of if it was added after the DOM was ready.

```
$(document).on('mouseout', '.other', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Notice we use `.stopPropagation()`, we do this so it doesn't arbitrarily fire the `.mouseout()` function on the `.ajax_popup_wrapper_wrapper`.

[Theoretical implementation (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ug5L6/)

Comment: Hi, in your example, the green div closes when you hover over the red one. But it should stay open !

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Thanks!

The only thing I had to change, was to remove mouseout() and replace it with mouseleave() ...

```
$('.ajax_popup_wrapper_wrapper').mouseleave(function(){
// remove div
```